# How to split a PDF by page by region and save it to a new PDF?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a multi-paged PDF file that for each page has 4 different regions I need to extract to separate PDF documents.  In the end, I want to extract ~`totalPages * 4` separate PDF files from this one PDF file.

There is PDFTextSplitterByArea that let's you define regions on the page and extract the text belonging to that region.  But I don't want only the text.  I want the entire PDF contents (layout, etc).

I've thought I could loop over the PDResources and check a bounding box to pull over the PDF elements within that box, but PDResources doesn't cover all of the elements.  This is where my lack of knowledge about PDF structure and pdfbox model is holding me back.  I also looked looping through the COSDictionary which seems more likely, but how do I reconstruct the page with the right elements from that region with the proper colorspace and fonts, etc?

I should add that I'm looking to produce a PDF with only PDF elements inside the region's bounding box.  This information is sensitive so it would not be acceptable to retain anything outside that area.  So using a cropbox would NOT be a solution.

Comment: *"I should add that ..."* - that means that you actually want a true redaction mechanism. That feature is not implemented as part of pdfbox yet.  Of course one can implement that based on pdfbox but as far as i know there is no such implementation publicly available.

Comment: In my particular case I am not concerned about overlap as the regions of content seems to be separate on the page.  If I had any overlap I'd simply omit anything that isn't contained within the region.  Any pointers on how to implement this?  I had seem posts about PDFStreamEngine, but as I started down that path I couldn't quite figure out how to get the bounding box of each element, and I struggled on how to rebuild the Page object properly.

Comment: @KJ I think his use of the term redaction mean something different than the colloquial use of the term.  If you are thinking about just striking through content like in a government documents redaction process then yes I think you have a point.  But what he means, I think, is a more expanded view of that where content is removed from the original that is outside a defined region.  And my vision of what I'm after is reconstructing the same elements that live within a defined region from the source PDPage object into a new PDPage object and save that is a separate PDF.

Comment: I guess then would I make a copy of each page (need some example code on how to copy a page), place the stamper annotations around 3 sections of the page, then remove everything tagged with the annotation?  How do you do that?  I've seen the PDRubberStampAnnotation, but I wasn't sure how that worked.  Please feel free to add an answer outlining this method.